# What can I use for PCB casing?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, cases

The size of my board is 13,5x14,5. I need some casing which will be used on device in a room that -24°C . Another requirement is PCB should not be screwed so that it can be unpluggable when it is needed. I couldn't find any clamp-like mounting equipment. I would be glad if someone can recommend something or at least keywords to search.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are asking for a case for a project that will operate in a -24°C environment, and my answer is based on this.

ABS enclosures are common, however this environment will [likely be too cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylonitrile_butadiene_styrene) for them.

A polycarbonate enclosure should fare better, as they [appear to be more tolerant of cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate).

Most hobby electronics stores should be able to sell you a suitable enclosure.

I would generally assume that anywhere that cold is also wet, so it would be best to select an enclosure with a seal, and seal any openings in the enclosure.